# DIV só ficar clicável se o RADIO estiver marcado

Tags: jquery, html, input, radiobutton

Gostaria que meu `<button id="bottaaoPA">Comprar</button>` só ficasse clicável se o `radio` estivesse marcado.

**Código:**

```js
$(function(){

  var contador = 0;

  $('.pa').click(function(){

    if(contador === 0)
    {
      $(this).addClass("select");
      $(this).hasClass("selectB");
      $("#bottaaoPA").css("display","block");
      $("#bottaaoPB").css("display","none");
      $("#bottaaoPC").css("display","none");
      contador = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).removeClass("select");
      $("#bottaaoPA").css("display","none"); //apenas para teste
      contador = 0;
    }
  });
});
$(function(){
  $("#bottaaoPA").click(function(){
    if($("input[name='bbt']").prop( "checked" ) &&    
       $("input[name='resp'").prop( "checked" ))
    {
      alert("Dois marcados");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  <h3><input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio1" name="bbt" value="bbt">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Regulamento Geral BBT.</a></h3><br />
  <h3><input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio2" name="resp" value="resp">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Termo de Isenção de Responsabilidade</a> do evento.</h3>
  <h5><img src="img/setaC-04.png"/><a href="#">Baixe aqui</a> a Ficha de Inscrição/Ficha Médica para a sua inscrição do evento.</h5>
</form>
<button id="bottaaoPA" disabled="disabled">Comprar</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ficaria assim com a `div`:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#bottaaoPA").off("click");
  
  $("#bottaaoPA").click(function(){
    if($("input[name='bbt']").prop( "checked" ) &&    
       $("input[name='resp'").prop( "checked" ))
    {
      alert("Dois marcados");
    }

  });
  $("input[name='bbt']").click(function(){
    verifica();
  });
  $("input[name='resp']").click(function(){
    verifica();
  });
  
  function verifica()
  {
    if($("input[name='bbt']").prop( "checked" ) &&    
       $("input[name='resp'").prop( "checked" ))
    {
      $("#bottaaoPA").on("click");
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
    <h3><input type="radio" name="bbt" value="bbt">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Regulamento Geral BBT.</a></h3><br />
    <h3><input type="radio" name="resp" value="resp">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Termo de Isenção de Responsabilidade</a> do evento.</h3>
    <h5><img src="img/setaC-04.png"/><a href="#">Baixe aqui</a> a Ficha de Inscrição/Ficha Médica para a sua inscrição do evento.</h5>
</form>
<div id="bottaaoPA">Comprar</div>
```

Ou pode ser (mas o `bottaaaoPA` deve ser um botão pois `div` não tem atributo `disabled`):

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[name='bbt']").change(function(){
    verifica();
  });
  $("input[name='resp']").change(function(){
    verifica();
  });
  $("#bottaaoPA").click(function(){
    alert("teste");
  });
  
  function verifica()
  {
    if($("input[name='bbt']").prop( "checked" ) &&    
       $("input[name='resp'").prop( "checked" ))
    {
      $("#bottaaoPA").prop("disabled", false);
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
    <h3><input type="radio" name="bbt" value="bbt">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Regulamento Geral BBT.</a></h3><br />
    <h3><input type="radio" name="resp" value="resp">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Termo de Isenção de Responsabilidade</a> do evento.</h3>
    <h5><img src="img/setaC-04.png"/><a href="#">Baixe aqui</a> a Ficha de Inscrição/Ficha Médica para a sua inscrição do evento.</h5>
</form>
<button id="bottaaoPA" disabled>Comprar</button>
```

Comment: Amigo não foi... ainda com 1 marcado da para aperta no botão :/

Comment: Aqui funciona perfeitamente, aperte em Executar trecho de código e verá. para ele não fazer nada quando apenas um radio estiver marcado basta apagar os `else if` e `else` que ele só fará algo se ambos tiverem marcado.

Comment: @Ivcs eu tirei so deixei o IF mas mesmo assim ele fica clicavel

Comment: Para deixar clicável ou não é só usando botão amigo, coloquei o jeito usando botão na resposta.

Comment: Sim ele ja esta assim com o disable mas se eu marca 1 ele ja fica clicável :/

Comment: Mano você está fazendo algo errado então, olhe na resposta no segundo `Executar trecho de código` só ativará o botão se os dois estiverem marcado.

Comment: Completei a resposta usando a `div`, com a função `on` e `off` do `jquery`. Agora com a div também funciona, só será clicável se os dois checkbox forem marcados.

Comment: Opaaa, agora foi descobri meu erro obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".radio").click(function() {
    if($("#radio1").is(":checked") && $("#radio2").is(":checked")) {
      $("#bottaaoPA").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  <h3><input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio1" name="bbt" value="bbt">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Regulamento Geral BBT.</a></h3>
  <br />
  <h3><input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio2" name="resp" value="resp">Li e concordo com o <a href="#">Termo de Isenção de Responsabilidade</a> do evento.</h3>
  <h5><img src="img/setaC-04.png"/><a href="#">Baixe aqui</a> a Ficha de Inscrição/Ficha Médica para a sua inscrição do evento.</h5>
</form>
<button id="bottaaoPA" disabled="disabled">Comprar</button>
```

Comment: Ele deu mais ou menos certo. pois preciso que o botão só fique ON se os 2 RADIO estiverem selecionados e não só um!

Comment: @kaiquemix você não especificou isso na sua pergunta. Mas, de qualquer forma, já editei minha resposta.

Comment: não foi, apertando 1 ele ainda da para apertar

Comment: @kaiquemix aqui funcionou corretamente. Você está fazendo algo errado.

Comment: Vou atualizar o meu la em cima apra você da uma olhada Igor

Comment: editei, poderia dar uma olhada